# How to find if object inside array is NOT empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Say I have an array, like so:

```
arr = [{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

I want to be able to know the length of the array, only counting objects within in it that have at least one property.

```
[{}, {name: "Derby County", odds: 2}, {}, {}] // 1

[{}, {name: "Derby County", odds: 2}, {name: "Fullham", odds: 3} ,{}] // 2
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length` will yield a non-zero result when there's at least one iterable, non-inherited property.

Comment: `detect when something is added` this has more than one way to interpret it, with quite different solutions

Comment: You're right @AndréWerlang I'll update OP now, thank you

Comment: I've updated the OP, hopefully that's clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
arr.filter(x => Object.keys(x).length).length
```

As explained in other answers, `Object.keys()` returns property names from a given object. The inner `.length` is a shortcut to filter only items that have at least one property. The outer `.length` tells how many objects fit the description.

**UPDATE:**

The `[].filter()` method takes a function that returns a thruthy/falsy value. A number greater than 0 is thruthy, so it's the same as `.length !== 0`.

The assumption here is that any element contained in the array is non-null. Under this assumption it makes no sense checking the object for null inside the `[].filter()`. When using TypeScript, it's a static check for `arr`. If the assumption is broken, then an error is thrown, which it's something I usually desire. I don't hide runtime errors. If there's a runtime error here, I'll review the assumption. Yet I'm not sure it's the case here.

Comment: Remember to check for null `arr.filter(x => x ? Object.keys(x).length > 0 : false).length;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry, I've updated the OP again! Hopefully now I've articulated myself properly

Comment: @A7DC the edit doesn't change the answer, it still complies, I guess the `.length` access made you think it would accumulate properties?

Comment: @ThilinaHasantha it's a valid assumption to expect the input array contains only non-null objects. Besides, it can be also desired it throws an error if that assumption fails

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
arr.map(x=> Object.keys(x).length)
```

you'll get:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

If the object is empty then there are no keys and so its length is 0.

If you need a true/false result do:

```
arr.map(x=> Object.keys(x).length).some(x=>x>0)
```

#### Examples:

```js
console.log("[{},{}]", [{},{}].map(x=> Object.keys(x).length).some(x=>x>0))

console.log("[{},{a: 1}]", [{},{a: 1}].map(x=> Object.keys(x).length).some(x=>x>0))
```